# How can I use a SQL Transaction when executing a set of statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm missing something about using transactions with MySQL. I have a script that deletes data data from some tables and then inserts data into those tables. I want it to rollback everything (deletes and any completed inserts) if there are any errors. I read the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html) on the subject and I understand that using `START TRANSACTION` will disable auto commit, yet when I purposely cause an error in my script the changes are not rolled back (i.e. the transaction isn't doing what I expect).

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905900/mysql-transaction-roll-back-on-any-exception) (and others like it) but they all use stored procedures. I don't want to use sprocs, I have a *.sql file that I execute in [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/) (MySQL management tool), just a bunch of statements.

Here is a trimmed down version of the script I'm working on:

```
-- Start the transaction
START TRANSACTION;

--  Delete all the table data
--  All other qb_* tables are deleted by CASCADING DELETEs
DELETE FROM `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_items`;
DELETE FROM `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_inventory_sites`;

-- Insert Inventory Site records
INSERT INTO `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_inventory_sites` (`site_id`, `name`) VALUES ('80000002-1477203394', 'CA-Orange');
INSERT INTO `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_inventory_sites` (`site_id`, `name`) VALUES ('80000001-1476941342', 'Drop Ship');

-- Insert Item records
INSERT INTO `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_items` (`item_id`, `name`, `item_number_type`, `type`) VALUES ('8000000A-1484095135', '- Internal Labor -', 'NONE', 'Service');

-- The following insert will throw an exception
INSERT INTO `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_items` (`item_id`, `name`, `item_numffffber_type`, `type`) VALUES ('80000024-1484102389', 'General Device Assembly Labor', 'NONE', 'Service');
INSERT INTO `manfstudio_dev`.`qb_items` (`item_id`, `name`, `item_number_type`, `type`) VALUES ('80000009-1483733754', 'Miscellaneous', 'NONE', 'Service');

-- Commit the transaction
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I want a single transaction with all the statements (2 deletes and ~200 inserts) to be rolled back if any of them throw an error. This is part of a short term workaround solution that will be throwaway in a few weeks, with that said I need to guarantee that a botched insert or update won't leave the system undefined or with the previous data gone. In other words, a reverted and stale dataset is better than an undefined or partial dataset.

Comment: It appears you're on the right track. . . http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: I read those docs, that's where I started. The thing is... it's not working. When an insert fails it's not rolling back the changes.